# Do-It-Yourself physics experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity, atomic-physics, home-experiment

Is there any simple experiment in physics of the first half of the 20th century I could do at home?  I tried to make a cloud chamber, but it didn't work at all... A spectrometer from a CD disk is already being implemented. I also thought about the double-slit experiment, but it was set up well before the given time frame (1900-1950). Requirements: the experiment should be conducted using readily available (not very expensive) materials; the experiment should somehow be related to the physics in the first half of the 20th century.

Comment: [Scientific American's "The Amateur Scientist"](https://www.amazon.com/Scientific-Americans-Amateur-Scientist-Collection/dp/097034760X) is an incredible collection of such experiments. If it doesn't have a home made cyclotron, it does at least have a home made "atom smasher". And 4 different ways to make a laser. And so much more.

Comment: One piece of 20th-century physics that's not present in your tags is chaos theory.  If you get your hands on an oscilloscope, you could [build a chaotic circuit](https://www.chaotic-circuits.com) at fairly little expense.  That said, chaos theory was really only developed in the second half of the 20th century (not the first.)

Comment: Millikan oil-drop experiment?

Answer (score 2):

The [first cyclotron](https://www2.lbl.gov/Science-Articles/Archive/rev-idea.html) was a tabletop device.

Then again, a cyclotron requires a source of ions, I don't know whether that is doable as a home project.

Also, I don't know how high of a vacuum is required.

The difficulty, of course, is that the experiments that have gone down in history are the ones that in their time were cutting edge. The mechanics will be high precision and the electronics will be high precision. I suspect the level of precision that was achievable in a cutting edge university laboratory in the 1930's is still quite hard to achieve in a home workshop, if at all.